# Implementing softmax() in C

Tags: c

The **[Softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)**, or **normalized exponential function**, is defined as:

$$
\sigma(z)_j = \frac{e^{zj}}{\sum^K_{k=1} e^{zk}} \text{for} \space j \space \text{in} \space [1, \dots, K]
$$

I am trying to implement this in C, starting with [an answer here](//stackoverflow.com/q/9906136).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void softmax(float *input, int input_len)
{
    assert (input != NULL);
    assert (input_len != 0);
    int i;
    float m;
    /* Find maximum value from input array */
    m = input[0];
    for (i = 1; i < input_len; i++) {
        if (input[i] > m) {
            m = input[i];
        }
    }

    float sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        sum += expf(input[i]-m);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
        input[i] = expf(input[i] - m - log(sum));

    }    
}

int main() {
   float arr[7] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
   softmax(arr, 7);
   printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], arr[6]);
}
```

Output:

```
0.024 0.064 0.175 0.475 0.024 0.064 0.175
```

Any suggestion and comment are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to [@Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/180506/29485) good ideas:

Consistency

1. Unclear that code uses `float` and `expf()`, yet `log(double)`.  Suggest `double` throughout or use `logf(float)`.

Minor stuff

2. `int input_len` and `assert (input_len != 0);` --> `assert(input_len > 0);`. Further: Unclear why code dis-allows `input_len == 0`. See below and suggest `assert(input_len >= 0);`
3. Array sizes are best indexed with type `size_t` vs. `int`.  Although rare, `int` may be insufficient.
4. `input[]` may contain [Not-A-Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), so recommend to not initialize `m` with `input[0]` as all subsequent `input[i] > m` will fail.  The change below also allows `input_len == 0`

   ```
   // float m = input[0];
   // for (i = 1; i < input_len; i++) {
   float m = -INFINITY;
   for (i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
     ...
   ```

---

```
static void softmax(float *input, size_t input_len) {
  assert(input);
  // assert(input_len >= 0);  Not needed

  float m = -INFINITY;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
    if (input[i] > m) {
      m = input[i];
    }
  }

  float sum = 0.0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
    sum += expf(input[i] - m);
  }

  float offset = m + logf(sum);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < input_len; i++) {
    input[i] = expf(input[i] - offset);
  }
}
```

Comment: I add `assert(input[i] == input[i]);` to check `input[i]` is not *NOT-A-NUMBERS*

Answer (score 9):

## Prefer `double` to `float` for calculations

Unless you're extremely constrained for space, or you have a platform with software floating-point (or very poor FP hardware), there's no reason to use `float`.

## Reduce the scope of index variable

Modern C allows us to declare `i` local to the loops:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < input_len;  i++)
```

## Hoist the `log(sum)` calculation

Your compiler's optimizer will probably spot that `log(sum)` does not change, but why not help it?

```
const double log_sum = log(sum);
for (int i = 0;  i < input_len;  i++) {
    input[i] = expf(input[i] - m - log_sum);
}
```

In fact, since `m` is also constant, we should hoist that, too:

```
const double scale = m + log(sum);
for (int i = 0;  i < input_len;  i++) {
    input[i] = expf(input[i] - scale);
}
```